# Low energy theory of any S-matrix is a QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory, effective-field-theory

I have seen similar claims to the following:
*Any (sufficiently nice) S-matrix at low energy can always be described by an effective Quantum Field Theory*. I would like to understand the extent of the evidence we have in support of this claim or if there is a more correct statement of it. Below are specific examples where a claim is made in this spirit.

1. Weinberg called it a "folk theorem" in p.8 of [hep-th/9702027](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9702027):

> [...] it is very likely that any quantum theory that at sufficiently low energy and large distances looks Lorentz invariant and satisfies the cluster decomposition principle will also at sufficiently low energy look like a quantum field theory.

2. The nLab page for [effective quantum field theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/effective+quantum+field+theory) states something more precise but I couldn't find any kind of evidence in support of the statement made there:

> The low energy expansion of any unitary, relativistic, crossing symmetric S-matrix can be described by an effective quantum field theory.

What kind of evidence is there for any of the above? Or is there another and more correct statement about the relationship between S-matrices at low energy and Quantum Field Theories?

Comment: Well, the arguments and example Weinberg gives in the talk itself are essentially quite exhaustive it seems to me. (At least to the point these statements can be made precise.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The informal reason is the following:

By Weinberg's cluster expansion analysis, a Lorentz-invariant S-matrix can be expressed formally in terms of some relativistic QFT whose action has all possible Lorentz-invariant interaction terms. Reexpand this formal action around the ground state, and regard the resulting fomal sum as a sum of $N$-particle contributions for $N=0,2,3,\ldots$; linear terms are absent by choice of the expansion point. Looking at the dimensions, the higher order contributions are likely to grow like increasing powers of the energy. At sufficiently low energy, these can be dropped. This leaves something renormalizable.

Of course this argument is quite ill-defined once one tries to make it more substantial. I don't think there is a more convincing argument.